# Counting number/share of groups under criteria

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, aggregate

I have the following data frame structure:

```
   Score  V1   V2   V3 ...
     1    12   15   0     
     2    17   25   13     
     3    0    0    18
     1    0    12   25     
     3    11   41   0    
     3    18   0    0
```

and I want to calculate for each `score` group (1/2/3 in my example) and for each column (V1/V2/V3...) the number of rows where the value was bigger than 0.

So, I'd like to get the following results:

```
   Score  V1    V2    V3 ...
     1    50%   100%  50%     
     2    100%  100%  100%     
     3    67%   33%   33%
```

I started to solve it using `dplyr`, but I'm stuck with the filtering part:

```
hun_percent <- 
  hun %>% 
  group_by(Score) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(n=n()))
```

Answer (score 0):

With base R, we can use `aggregate` and for every `Score` we can calculate the ratio of values which are greater than 0 and total number of values.

```
aggregate(.~Score, hun, function(x) length(x[x>0])/length(x) * 100)

#Score        V1        V2        V3
#1     1  50.00000 100.00000  50.00000
#2     2 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000
#3     3  66.66667  33.33333  33.33333
```

---

I am not sure if there is a better option with `dplyr`. However, one similar way is

```
library(dplyr)
hun %>%
 group_by(Score) %>%
 summarise_each(funs(length(.[.>0])/length(.) * 100))
```

Comment: Also `rowsum(+(df[-1] > 0), df[, 1])/tabulate(df[, 1]) * 100` as a vectorized option

Comment: @DavidArenburg looks impressive. Add as an answer?

Comment: It's not so safe though. It needs `df[, 1]` to be both numeric and sorted (like in OPs example) so I guess not general enough for answer.

Comment: @RonakShah Thank for your answer. Just a little thing.. when I'm applying your 2 options (base R or `dplyr`) I'm getting small differences. Do you know why it happens? (maybe numbers `round`)

Comment: @staove7 differences as in how? Example?

Comment: @RonakShah differences in values... e.g., I get for `score=1` share of 1.68... percent in one method and 1.75... percent in the other

Comment: @staove7 that's strange. I get same values using both the functions.

Comment: @RonakShah it is wierd. Tks anyway :)

Comment: @staove7 Could you share an example for which you are facing this issue? As the solution works for the given example in the question, isn't it?